# Catching errors from SQLite in Common Lisp

Tags: sqlite, common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp

I'm using the SQLite wrapper from Quicklisp, which is described [here](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-sqlite/). I notice that, for example, `execute-non-query`, returns nothing, but will throw `sqlite-error`s. However, I'm not sure how to handle them - as far as I can tell, `catch` needs an explicit tag, and I'm not sure how the wrapper tags them.

Basically, I would like to do something like this:

```
(if (no-error (execute-non-query *db* query-string))
    (do-happy-thing)
    (report-error))
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`handler-case` is  your friend.

```
(handler-case 
    (progn
      (execute-non-query *db* query-string)
      (do-happy-thing))
  (sqlite-error (err) (report-error err))) ; err contains additional information
```

Comment: `Report-error` should be named `do-sad-thing` here.